# Como herdar atributos de 2 classes diferentes em JAVA?

Tags: java

[image: UML]

Estou tentando herdar os atributos das classes Física e Jurídica, mas sei que em Java não existe herança multipla. Como posso utilizar os atributos da classe Fisica e Juridica na classe Cliente?

Comment: Nao existe herança multipla em java.

Comment: REcomendo a leitura dos topicos marcados, eles explicam os motivos de nao existir herança multipla e há tambem algumas formas alternativas a isso.

Comment: Java não suporta Herança Multipla, sugiro que tente modificar sua arquitetura de classes para atender sua necessidade